# Problems displaying 3D content with Nvidia graphics card in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opengl, bumblebee, optimus

I recently got a new laptop (Thinkpad T480) which has Intel integrated "UHD Graphics 620" and an Nvidia MX150, and I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the nvidia driver alright, and I believe I am using the Nvidia card successfully to run my laptop's display/external monitors.

However, I have a problem displaying 3D content: when I try to create a 3D plot in Mathematica, the program simply crashes (this does not happen when I switch back to using my Intel card with `prime-select`). Furthermore, when I try to launch Steam, I get the error "OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display" (and again this does not occur and steam works normally when I use my integrated graphics). Finally, with the nvidia card selected, I am unable to even login to the standard gnome desktop environment (I simply get booted back out to the login screen). Luckily I normally use xmonad, and that seems to work fine.

I tried reinstalling `xserver-xorg` which was suggested somewhere online but that didn't help. I saw other information about installing Bumblebee, but all of that seems to be from many years ago (and the latest release of Bumblebee is over 5 years old so I was a little wary about it). Nevertheless, I tried installing Bumblebee and, after modifying `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` to use the correct directory for the libGL.so.1 driver, I was able to run a game through Steam. I never tried running Steam itself using `optirun` but I ran Civilization V with `optirun` through Steam and it seemed to work as intended, and I could see that the Nvidia card was being used with the program `NVTOP`. Civilization V does involve 3D graphics but I'm not sure if it uses OpenGL. I also tried running Minecraft (which I think does use OpenGL) through `optirun` and just got a window with a black screen. I tried `optirun glxgears` and got an error that said

```
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
```

I did some more research and found that perhaps Bumblebee was not the way to go (multiple reports of bugs with Ubuntu 18.04)... so now I am back in the situation I described in the first and second paragraphs above. I figured it was time to ask for help.

Below are the outputs to some commands I have seen in other questions related to this issue:

Here is my output when I try to run `glxinfo`:

```
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Here is my output when I try to run `glxgears`:

```
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

Here is my output when I run `lspci -nnnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620 [17aa:225e]
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] [10de:1d10] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Lenovo GP108M [GeForce MX150] [17aa:225e]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and installed the Nvidia driver before anything else, and that worked (everything seems to be working now). I believe something else I had previously installed (not sure what) was conflicting with some of the files required by my graphics setup.